# asp.net core 5 web api swagger does not give application/xml options

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I've added the xml serializer formatters to my web api:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{   
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        .AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = $"Test", Version = "v1" });
    });
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Evaluate : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<Evaluate> _logger;

    public Evaluate(ILogger<Evaluate> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<MyResponse> Post(MyRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I browse to the swagger page, I only get text/plain, application/json and text/json as options for request/response formats.  I've tried decorating my MyResponse and MyRequest classes with [Serializeable] and [DataContract]/[DataMember] attributes but no change.

How do I get swagger to recognize that I have added the Xml serializers?

Comment: Hi @Jeremy,I just add the `.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` in my asp.net core 5 project,the swagger will contain `text/xml`,`application/xml` and so on options in request/response format. Please try to create a new project and check if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I noticed an error in the eventlog saying there was something in my model that couldn't be serialized by the XmlSerializer.  The model had an IEnumerable<> property.  When the XmlSerializer can't serialize/deserialze a model,  the swagger ui just omits the xml options.